# How to Remove/Delete Deleted Projects from TFS Source Control

Tags: tfs

I'm using TFS 2012 (Free preview).

I have a bunch of projects in my solution under source control.

Sometimes I find it the easiest solution to a problem to just scrap an entire project and start over. However, everytime I do that I run into trouble because the "deleted" project stays in the Source Control Explorer with a "deleted" status (Show/Hide Deleted Items button) and, at best, sticks around as junk, and at worst leads, to conflicts later on.

How can I get all traces of them removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [tf destroy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) command. This is non recoverable.

Comment: Can this command be performed through a GUI in Visual Studio, perhaps in Source Control Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

[TFSDeleteProject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181482.aspx) permanently destroys the team project, after which it cannot be recovered.

```
TFSDeleteproject [/q] [/force] [/excludewss] /collection:URL TeamProjectName
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and tf destroy? I believe yours will destroy my entire solution as it is called a "Team Project" itself (in Web Access at least)

Comment: Yes it will. Sorry, I misread the manual. `tf destroy` is what you need.